# CORS protection problem through Nginx in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, cors

Here is my nginx.conf file

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend-app:4200;
        }

        location /auth {
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            }
            if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            }
            if ($request_method = 'PUT') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            }

            rewrite ^/auth/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://auth-service:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  auth-db:
    build:
      context: ./penai-backend/auth-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-auth-db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  auth-service:
    build:
      context: ./penai-backend/auth-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-auth-service
    depends_on:
      - auth-db

  frontend-app:
    build:
      context: ./penai-frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - auth-db
      - auth-service

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - frontend-app

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

When I send a POST request from my frontend application (next-js). I got CORS (403 status code) error. I am trying to solve this problem for a long time but I could not. Any help for solving this problem ?

Here is the error code in the browser: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()